# fail jenkins ssh script in case a port is unreachable

Tags: bash, jenkins, ssh

I am trying to make a final check on my jenkins script, in case a port is available I want the script (build) to be a success, and in case its not available to mark it as failure.
How can I achieve this easily?

this is the final check

```
$ nc -zv 10.10.10.24 3306
Connection to localhost 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use catchError() to explicitly set build results:

```
catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
  sh 'nc -zv 10.10.10.24 3306'
}
```

See: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/

But from what I understand from your question, this may already happen by just executing the sh step. If it fails, the pipeline will also fail in this stage / step (If you don't catch / handle errors in another way).

Edit: Maybe you also want to set a timeout for nc like:

```
nc -zv 10.10.10.24 3306 -w 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The docs seems great, the question is how to write it inside the remote ssh host build step, I am using the UI

Comment: Ok, so I understand you are using "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh" in the UI? Then you should just add `nc -zv 10.10.10.24 3306 -w 60` as a "Post build script". If this fails, your build also fails, if the connections succeeds, you build is successful.

Comment: Thanks, but what is actually the reason that it will fail the script? Does jenkins look for the word fail? does the command return exit code of some sort to the ssh step?

Comment: Your `nc` command is the script, so it will either run successful (exit code = 0), which will result in your job continuing or being successful or it will fail (exit code > 0), which will fail the "Post build script" and therefore also your build.